# trying to hide an event two days after it's passed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to hide an event two days after it's passed in php (using a mysql query). There are two date options. Start date, and End date. I can't seem to figure out how to make the query work.

```
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__events_items');
    $query->where('date2 >= "'.$today.'"');
    $query->where('date2 <= "'.$sixmths.'"');
    $query->where('state = 1');
    $query->order('date1 asc');
```

I've tried

```
$today      = @date('Y-m-d');
$enddate        = @date('Y-m-d',(strtotime(@date('Y-m-d')."+ 2 days")));
```

But obviously the end date won't be greater or equal to $enddate.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From my understanding of the query, it's currently hiding events as soon as they are passed.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, currently it's hiding the event when it's passed.. I need to hide it two days after it's passed.

Comment: What is the purpose of the error-suppression operator `@` in `@date('Y-m-d');`?

Comment: The @ is just because of the development server I'm working on lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either modify today like so:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days'));
```

Or modify your query like so :

```
 $query->select('*');
 $query->from('#__events_items');
 $query->where('date2 >= "'.$today.'" - INTERVAL 2 DAY');
 $query->where('date2 <= "'.$sixmths.'"');
 $query->where('state = 1');
 $query->order('date1 asc');
```

I would say the second is probably better form since having $today represent two days ago would be nasty self documenting code.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's worked! :D Will accept the answer when I can lol